# Can't install Scrapy

Tags: python, pip, scrapy

I would like to install the Scrapy package. 
I tried with `pip install Scrapy` but it didn't work, a lot of errors are displayed but I think this is the main error : `Building wheel for Twisted (setup.py) ... error`.

I searched on this forum and found something : try to install it with the Anaconda Prompt. I use PyCharm so I thought it would be useless but I tried.
I did this : `conda install -c anaconda twisted`.

No error : `# All requested packages already installed.`.

The problem is that it is obviously not installed since if I repeat the command `pip install Scrapy`, I always have the same errors.

If someone have an idea, it will be awesome !

Comment: So you installed it with Anaconda, but you don’t know how to get PyCharm to use your Anaconda environment?

Answer (score -1):

try this. Works for me in pycharm.

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org Scrapy
```

Comment: I had the same error. I wrote the order in the CMD, did you ?

Comment: I wrote it in pycharm terminal